# How to make a list item show/hide another DIV?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 2 lists:

· source selector; · 
· content of the selected source;

I need to know how to turn each item of the source list into a button, to show only it's content when clicked, and stay highlighted when selected, just like the iTunes Smart Playlists (for example).

Someone can make this code for me? I have jQuery already, but i can't make it work...

```css
#tabs {
 z-index: 1;
 top: 60px;
 height: 576px;
 width: 244px;
 font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size: 12px;
 padding-top: 5px;
 float: left;
 overflow: scroll;
 max-height: 591px;
 left: -40px;
    outline: dotted;
 } 


#Source {
 height: 656px;
 width: 244px;
 background: #EEE;
font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size: 12px;
    outline: dotted;
 }



#content {
 height: 300px;
 width: 500px;
 text-align:right;
 overflow-y: scroll;
 text-align:center;
    outline: dotted;

 } 

.list {
 font-family: sans-serif;
 margin: auto;
 width: 300px;
 font-size: 12px;
 max-height: 654px;
 padding-top: 30px;
}
.list > li {
  display:block;
  float: left;
  padding: 12px;
  line-height: 15px;

 }
  
#tabs > li {
  display:block;
  float: bottom;
  padding: 3px;
  padding-left: 13px;
  line-height: 15px;
  
}
```

```html
<div id="content">

  <div id="MRV">
    <ul class="list" id:"mrv">
       <li>
        <div id="thumb"><img src="lib/mrv/MRV-40x30_01.png" width="100px" height="75"/></div>
        <br> 
     <p class="ref">MRV 1</p>
        <h3 class="empresa">MRV Engenharia</h3>
        <p class="tags"><!-- Atenção Uso Obrigatório de Capacetes e Calçados de Segurança --></p>
      </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  </div>
  
<div id="source">
  <ul id="tabs">
    <li>
<img src="" width="32px" height="32px" img class="avatar"/>  Ambev
</li>

<li>
<img src="" width="32px" height="32px" img class="avatar"/> Bianchini
</li>

<li>
<img src="" width="32px" height="32px" img class="avatar"/> MRV Engenharia
</li>

<li>
<img src="" width="32px" height="32px" img class="avatar"/> White Martins
</li>

</ul>
```

Comment: please share what you've tried so far

Comment: if you supply the last ingredient your jQuery code, we will definatly cook something for you

Comment: You've to try before posting a question, that is how you learn.

Comment: You could also use the jQuery-UI Tabs widget.

Comment: "Can someone make this code for me?" StackOverflow is Not Your Personal Coding Service. If you need a programmer, hire one.

Comment: I've tried. Unsuccessfully.

Comment: I just answered a similar request here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31466943/javascript-getelementbyid-start-with/31467127#31467127